# Is there a simple, analytical formula for the lunar phase brightness curve?

Tags: the-moon, light, moon-phases

Brightness of the lunar disk varies as a function of phase angle. This phenomenon is very well established, as is the increase in brightness at low phase angles.

Is there a simple analytical formula that describes this function? It looks like brightness could be modeled as an exponential as a function of phase angle, modulo the opposition surge.

Thanks.

EDIT: I realize that these effects depend on the wavelength of the reflected light. I'm looking for an average curve, though.

[image: Lunar brightness curve, pointing out the opposition surge]

Comment: Could you source that image and/or data? Presumably, curve fitting methods could find an arbitrarily good match? http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1991PASP..103.1033K may also be helpful?

Answer (score 4):

The magnitude of the Moon without the *opposition surge* is given by a simple equation:

$m = -12.73 + 1.49 \cdot |\psi| + 0.043 \cdot \psi^4,$

where $\psi$ is the *phase angle* in radians [(Allen 1976)](http://esoads.eso.org/abs/1976asqu.book.....A).  This can be converted to flux using $m \propto -2.5 \cdot ^{10}\!\log F$,
where $^{10}\!\log$ denotes the 10-base logarithm (as opposed to e.g. the natural log).

For the increase in flux due to the variable distance and opposition surge, I multiply F with the factor

$\left(\frac{\Delta_0}{\Delta}\right)^2  \cdot  \max\left(1, 1.35 - 2.865 \cdot |\psi| \right),$

where $\Delta_0$ and $\Delta$ are the mean and current distance to the Moon, respectively.  However, I can't find a reference for the last term at the moment, and I can't remember where I obtained it.  I'll post that information if I find it.

Comment: The reference can be taken as [Krisciunas, Schaefer, _"A model of the Brightness of Moonlight"_](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1086/132921), which says: _"For $|\alpha| < 7°$ the lunar opposition effect should be taken into account, in which case the derived value of $B_{\text{moon}}$ must be multiplied by a factor in between 1.00 and
1.35."_

Comment: I *think* the correction can be found in Schaefer B., "To the visual limits", Sky & Telescope vol. 95, No. 5, p 57 (1998), but I can't get hold of a copy and I'm not sure it is the original reference.

Comment: This article (which is easily googlable BTW) only shows a program with a magical addition `CM` to the lunar magnitude, it doesn't discuss the meaning.

Comment: @Ruslan CM is the magnitude correction for the different optical bands (U,B,V,R,I).  I got the article from a colleague; I haven't discovered an opposition surge in it.  I was mistaken...